# Ionic Tinder cards 2 return cards to the end of the stack

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using [this code pen](http://codepen.io/loringdodge/pen/BNmRrK)  to create a stack of "swipebale" cards in my Ionic application.
I want to make some changes to it.

Now I have this:

[image: picture]

1) I want to Inverse the tunnel view "up" instead of "down"
2) I want each swiped card to return at the end of the stack (instead of discarded).

If anybody can show me where to start.
I changed the "discard" function:

```
              <div class="discard" ng-click="onClickTransitionOut(card)">DISCARD</div>
          <img ng-src="{{ card.image }}">
        </div>
      </td-card>
```

To this:

```
 <div class="discard" ng-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft(card)">DISCARD</div>
          <img ng-src="{{ card.image }}">
        </div>
```

But the swiping does not work.
And I  changed the `removeCard` function to this

```
     $scope.$on('removeCard', function(event, element, card) {
    var discarded = $scope.cards.master.splice($scope.cards.master.indexOf(card), 1);
    $scope.cards.discards.push(discarded);
  });

  $scope.cardSwipedLeft = function(index) {
    console.log('LEFT SWIPE');
    var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
    $scope.cards.push(card);
  };
  $scope.cardSwipedRight = function(index) {
    console.log('RIGHT SWIPE');
    var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
    $scope.cards.push(card);
  };

})
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is the whole controller:

```
 <ion-pane ng-controller="CardsCtrl" class="background-grey">

  <!-- *************************
    TD Cards
    - We start off with an ng-if so that the cards are not generated
      unless $scope.cards is not 'null'
  ************************* -->
  <div>
    <td-cards>
      <td-card ng-repeat="card in cards.active"  on-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft($index)" on-swipe-right="cardSwipedRight($index)">
        <div class="image" ng-controller="CardCtrl">
          <img ng-src="{{ card.image }}">
        </div>
      </td-card>

    </td-cards>
  </div>

</ion-pane>
```

And the **JS**

```
    .controller('CardsCtrl', function($scope, TDCardDelegate, $timeout) {

  var cardTypes = [
    { image: 'img/cards/ASE card.png' },
    { image: 'img/cards/EDP card.png' },
    { image: 'img/cards/R2A card.png' },
    { image: 'img/cards/WTR card.png' },
    { image: 'img/cards/RRH card.png' },
    { image: 'img/cards/Staffing.png' },
    { image: 'img/cards/Intercontrat.png' }
  ];


  $scope.cards = {
    master: Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0),
    active: Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0),

  }

  $scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
    $scope.cards.active.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.addCard = function() {
    var newCard = cardTypes[0];
    $scope.cards.active.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
  }


  $scope.$on('removeCard', function(event, element, card) {
    $scope.cards.push(card);
  });

  $scope.cardSwipedLeft = function(index) {
    console.log('LEFT SWIPE');
    var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
    $scope.cards.push(card);
  };
  $scope.cardSwipedRight = function(index) {
    console.log('RIGHT SWIPE');
    var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
    $scope.cards.push(card);
  };

})

.controller('CardCtrl', function($scope, TDCardDelegate) {

});
```

Comment: what error are you seeing, looks like you are passing in the entire card object as a reference, not the index.. use `ng-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft($index)"` instead

Comment: I am getting "gesture not defined"

Comment: You need to have the `ngTouch` module installed : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Comment: I updated my post with the error log

Comment: I added ng-touch. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

So when you are using ionic's gestures you need to apply their own directives .

In your HTML you need to replace the `ng-swipe-left` with ionic's gesture : [OnSwipe](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onSwipe/)

Like so :

```
<div class="discard" on-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft($index)">DISCARD</div>
          <img ng-src="{{ card.image }}">
        </div>
```

This will use the gestures defined by ionic.

Comment: I still have the same errors as mentioned in the picture above. Only the first card is swiped. After that, it is "gesture not defined"

Comment: what other gestures have you got attached ? Maybe you have an `ng-swipe-right` floating around ?

Comment: I added the whole controller to my post

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to inverse the tunnel view, but here is how you can return each card at the end of the stack instead of discarding it.  Hope this helps at least.

```
$scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
    var loTopCard =  $scope.cards.active[index];
    $scope.cards.active.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('Card Count after Remove ' + $scope.cards.active.length);
    $scope.cards.active.push(loTopCard);
    console.log('Card Count after add ' + $scope.cards.active.length);

  };
```